# Blender hair particles keep changing during Cycles render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

I have an animal model that uses Blender's built-in hair particle as fur, then I noticed if I didn't have persistent data turned on then the particles would just keep changing positions on the model's faces. Which is BAD. The project is over 1000 frames, so I will have to stop rendering a few times. I start rendering during the night and stop during the day.

So the **problem** is that every time I render, then the hair particles have a new position for the next 200 frames. So every 6 sec the fur just changes, which is pretty jarring when watching the animation.

Currently, I'm on 3.6 lts, when I used 3.3 lts this wasn't an issue at all.

Little more information about the project:
Particle hair is placed after all deformations modifiers including the sub. It's not the modifier placement. I haven't done anything fancy, I just added the particle hair and tweaked a few hair shape settings, so all the default settings should be applied.

My curve settings are:
Rounded Ribbons
Shape = Strip
Both Curve and Additional subdivision = 2

Any help would appreciated!

Comment: Maybe enable the Use Modifier Stack option of the hair particle?